# Does the function being optimized via Lagrange multipliers have to be $C^1$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I have found many textbooks that state the method of Lagrange multipliers as follows:

> **Theorem.** Let $f, g: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be $C^1$ functions and $S=\{x \in \mathbb R^n \ | \ g(x)=0\}$ be a surface such that $\nabla g(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in S$. Then, if $f|_S$ has an extremum at $x_0$, there exists a $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ such that $\nabla f(x_0) = \lambda \nabla g(x_0)$.
>
> **Theorem.** Let $f, g_1, \dotsc, g_m: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be $C^1$ functions and $S=\{x \in \mathbb R^n \ | \ g_1(x)=\cdots=g_m(x)=0\}$ be a surface such that $\{\nabla g_1(x), \dotsc, \nabla g_m(x)\}$ are linearly independent for all $x \in S$. Then, if $f|_S$ has an extremum at $x_0$, the gradient $\nabla f(x_0)$ is in the linear span of the vectors $\{\nabla g_1(x_0), \dotsc, \nabla g_m(x_0)\}$.

The requirement that the constraint functions be $C^1$ is necessary to apply the Implicit Function Theorem.

However, despite the fact that nearly all resources I have read require the function $f$ to be $C^1$, none of the proofs appear to use this assumption. **Do the theorems hold with the weaker assumption that $f$ is merely differentiable?**

Comment: Nice question, but I don't know if the answer is easy. [These things can be subtle](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/the-inverse-function-theorem-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps/) if one downgrades "smooth" to "differentiable" (and in this context, "smooth" means $C^1$).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you for the resource. However, I suspect that the $C^1$ requirement can be dropped because the Implicit Function Theorem is applied to $g$, not $f$, and only the Chain Rule is applied to $f$.

Comment: That is true. I think that you are right. In geometrical language, the problem is to ensure that the zero set of g is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$, and there you need smoothness through the implicit function theorem. Once that is ensured, I see no problem in simply differentiating $f$, even without smoothness.